# How to get a 3d character already textured with black contours in EEVEE

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I have created and textured a 3d character inside character creator 3 by reallusion and I've exported it with the blender preset in FBX format and then I've imported it in Blender 2.81. I would like to render it with black outlines with EEVEE. I would like that you point me on the right shader configuration nodes and/or tutorial. I don't want a toon shader. I'm interested only to get the black outlines. This is the 3d character :

[image: a]

This is how the black outlines should be :

[image: b]

Comment: Seems like Freestyle is what you want.

Comment: can you point me on a tutorial about freestyle on eevee ?